# pChart, how to display week start or end date with month like "12/2-8" on x-axis?

Tags: php, pchart

Right now my `pchart` week graph display like this way,

[image]

**But I want to 
display week on `x-axis 12/2-8, 12/9-15` ('month' followed by '/' followed by 'start date', followed by '-', then 'end date')"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate the legend you can have

```
$weekLegend = getWeekLegend();
var_dump($weekLegend); // for debug purpose
```

Output

```
array (size=8)
  0 => string '12/09-15' (length=8)
  1 => string '12/16-22' (length=8)
  2 => string '12/23-29' (length=8)
  3 => string '12/30-05' (length=8)
  4 => string '01/06-12' (length=8)
  5 => string '01/13-19' (length=8)
  6 => string '01/20-26' (length=8)
  7 => string '01/27-02' (length=8)
```

Adding it to your dataset defination

```
// Dataset definition
$DataSet = new pData;
$DataSet->AddPoint($data,"Serie1");
$DataSet->AddPoint(getWeekLegend(),"Serie2");
$DataSet->AddAllSeries();
$DataSet->SetAbsciseLabelSerie("Serie2"); //<------ set pChat to use legend
```

Function Used

```
function getWeekLegend($week = 8) {
    $start = new DateTime();
    $start->modify("last sunday");
    while ( $week > 0 ) {
        $date = $start->format("m");
        $date .= "/";
        $date .= $start->format("d");
        $date .= "-";
        $start->modify("+6 day");
        $date .= $start->format("d");
        $start->modify("+1 day");
        $weekLegend[] = $date;
        $week --;
    }
    return $weekLegend ;
}
```